# missing path in shopware svg icon

Tags: svg, frontend, shopware, arrows, shopware6

normally in sw6 the slider element arrows look like the example below.

```
<span class="icon icon-arrow-head-right">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <defs>
   <path id="icons-default-arrow-head-right-a" d="m11.5 7.9142 10.2929 10.293c.3905.3904 1.0237.3904 1.4142 0 .3905-.3906.3905-1.0238 0-1.4143l-11-11c-.3905-.3905-1.0237-.3905-1.4142 0l-11 11c-.3905.3905-.3905 1.0237 0 1.4142.3905.3905 1.0237.3905 1.4142 0L11.5 7.9142z"></path>
  </defs>
  <use fill="#758CA3" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="rotate(90 11.5 12)" xlink:href="#icons-default-arrow-head-right-a"></use>
 </svg>
</span>
```

In one of our dev shops we have a strange behavior, where it looks like this:

```
<span class="icon icon-arrow-head-right">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <use transform="rotate(90 11.5 12)" xlink:href="#icons-default-arrow-head-right" fill="#758CA3" fill-rule="evenodd"></use>
 </svg>
</span>
```

the **defs > path** structure is missing.
i can't find any reason therefore. disabled all plugins. sw6 is the latest version and i could not reproduce it in another setting.
how can i find out, what could be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: it may be a typo: use `xlink:href="#icons-default-arrow-head-right-a"`  instead of xlink:href="#icons-default-arrow-head-right"

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of that issue occurring before in regular installations but it might be necessary to generate the icons for the storefront manually. There's a CLI command for that.

```bash
bin/console theme:prepare-icons /absolute/path/to/platform/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/dist/assets/icon/default/ default -c true -r evenodd -f #12ef21
```

If that fails check the directory used in that command and verify that `arrow-head-right.svg` didn't actually get altered somehow.

Comment: thanks for your hint. i did:


`$ bin/console theme:prepare-icons vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/dist/assets/icon/default default -c true -r evenodd`

with the -f #12ef21 it gave me an exception:
_The "--fillcolor" option requires a value._

sadly after all its still the same problem.

i took a look into the arrow-head-right.svg. this file is different for me locally and serverside the same way. locally with path id and xlink:href _#icons-default-arrow-head-right-a_ the serverside one without the _-a_.

me and no one else modified these files by hand, afaik

Comment: if i change the files on the server with the ones from the local machine, it makes no difference. generated the icons manually, but still no change

Comment: Do you use a theme? Themes may come with their own icon packs. There's a twig token parser that resolves `{% sw_icon 'arrow-head-right' %}` to include `src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/utilities/icon.html.twig`. Maybe try and add some dumps inside that template to see where the icon is sourced from.

Comment: i tried it with the default theme and a custom theme, did not change anything

Comment: Maybe try `grep --include=\*.svg -rnw . -e 'icons-default-arrow-head-right'` inside the shopware root directory and see what comes up. The incomplete file must be located somewhere.

Comment: that gave me quiet some output :D now i have to find the files without -a and replace them?

Comment: That would be my best guess :)